# Function with async operation that works for script-tag and as standalone

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a function in a file:

```
foo.js:

(function(){
   return {
      loadStuff: function(callback){
         setTimeout(function() { callback() }, 2000) 
      }
   }

})()
```

I have to run `loadStuff` in two different ways:

- first: when I get the file loaded by javascript engine itself (let's say via XHR and `eval`), then I can call it passing a callback (that's already possible)
- second: when it's loaded in a script tag, it still should call `loadStuff` automatically, although without a callback this time

How should I change the code to make `loadStuff` work both ways? I don't want to call `loadStuff` twice though: so for the first case I want to call it with callback, not like it would call it the first time function loaded (without callback) and then again with callback. I just need it to run `loadStuff` once, with callback.

So.

- when `<script src='foo.js' />` it should call `loadStuff` automatically
- when the function is string and I do this:

  ```
  fn = eval(fnStr)
  fn.loadStuff(function(){
     console.log("stuff loaded")
  })
  ```

It should call `loadStuff` only once

Comment: So basically you are saying that you want to call it twice without calling it twice... I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

foo.js:

```
(function(){
   var called = false,
       loadStuff = function(callback){
         called = true;
         setTimeout(function() { callback && callback() }, 2000) 
      };
   setTimeout(function(){!called && loadStuff();}, 13); //autolaunch if needed
   return {
      loadStuff: loadStuff
   }

})()
```